Insertar datos a una tabla temporal que obtengo de un Procedimiento Almacenado en SYBASE!
Estoy tratando de insertar información a una tabla temporal, la data que quiero insertar la estoy obteniendo de un SP.
Haciendo la misma prueba en SqlServer esto me funciona correctamente, pero al intentar hacerlo en SYBASE me marca el siguiente error de sintaxis: Error (156) Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
--Crear la tabla temporal
CREATE TABLE #TablaTemporal2 (
    Valor1 VARCHAR(50),
    Valor2 VARCHAR(50),
    valor3 VARCHAR(50),
    valor4 VARCHAR(50),
    valor5 VARCHAR(50)
)

--Ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado y guardar resultados en tabla temporal
INSERT INTO #TablaTemporal2
EXEC dbo.Usp_ProcedimientoTest

--Consultar la tabla temporal para verificar los resultados
SELECT * FROM #TablaTemporal

Como podría solventar este problema, o en su caso de que otra forma podría aplicar esta funcionalidad en SYBASE??

Lo intentaste usando OPENQUERY ?

No estoy familiarizado con sybase, pero ciertamente no es 100% compatible con T-SQL, en lo que respecta el EXEC, por lo que dice la documentación, en caso que tengas más de una fila, tienes que pasar por un cursor para procesar los datos recibidos: https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/iqrefbb654.htm
